# How to determine the conditions under whicht a time series is weakly stationary

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, stationarity

> Let $A, B$ be two uncorrelated random variables with mean $\mu_{A}, \mu_{B}$ and variances $\sigma_{A}^{2}, \sigma_{B}^{2},$ respectively. For some $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2},$ set
>
> $X_{t}=A \cos (\theta t)+B \sin (\theta t), \quad t \in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> Under which conditions on $A, B$ and $\theta$ do we have a weakly stationary time series. Calculate the spectral measure of the stationary $X_{t}$.

So I thought about checking whether I can deduce the appropriate values by plugging in $X_t$ into the defining conditions for a weakly stationary stochastic process. These are given in the following definition

> A real valued stochastic process $\left\{X_{t}: t \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ is said to be (weakly) stationary if
>
> 1. $\mathrm{E}\left[X_{t}^{2}\right]<\infty \quad$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$
> 2. $\mathrm{E}\left[X_{t}\right]=\mu \quad$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$
> 3. $\operatorname{cov}\left(X_{s}, X_{s+t}\right)=r_{t}$ for all $s, t \in \mathbb{Z}$
>    $\left\{r_{t}, t \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ is called the autocovariance function (acf).

My problem now is that first this seems like a really tedious way to solve the problem and second that I can't really come up with suitable conditions using this approach. The only result I have so far is that $\mu_A = \mu_B = 0$ by using condition 2. from the definition. Is there something else I could try ?

Comment: Share your calculations on the third one (the most tedious one), and we can help you get unstuck.